# PostgreSQL or mySQL best for daily log website?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I know that both these databases are better for different scenarios but in terms of a website where users will login and enter numerical data to a daily log, which one would it be best to use? I read that mySQL is faster to begin with but PostgreSQL is more scalable if the website were to start getting a lot of users?

The downside is that my host only offers mySQL and so to use postgreSQL I would have to purchase VPS hosting which is more expensive. I have also read people advising people to not worry about it to begin with, however it concerns me that I would have to rewrite queries and forms if I later moved to postgreSQL? I would appreciate everyone's thoughts on this.

I don't understand why people have given this question negative marks when I clearly stated that I am from a finance background and only started learning 3 weeks ago. I think you need to remember that everyone has to start somewhere and that we haven't all been doing this as a job/hobby for years. I would love to see some of you come out of your comfort zone and come and do my job for a day as you would be equally as clueless and I can guarantee that I would not be so rude as some of you have been here. You should be trying to create an environment of learning and innovation, rather than an environment of arrogance. If everyone knew everything, what would be the point in this website?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, but you should probably think about exactly what you want to do with the website and then be more specific as to the database use for that purpose.

Comment: The website allows users to create an account and then login on a daily basis and add numerical data which needs to be stored. The database is queried when they login and displayed in a chart. The question is if I want to start a website of this kind, and want to be able to scale it without difficulty, which is the best solution, thanks

Comment: Either database will provide you ability to do this.  The question is what are you going to do afterwards and how much data will there be?

Comment: I know they will both allow me to do this, I have a crude working model using mySQL but my question is to whether there is any limitations of using mySQL when the business scales. In my mind, I didn't want to use a database if it limited the future scaling of the website, but it seems from other answers that the webpages I have read are inaccurate appraisals of mySQL and that it is a scalable solution. thanks for your responses

Comment: It all depends on what you're storing and what you want to use it for which you still haven't said.

Comment: Data entered by uses will be stored in DB. When they login, the data will be queried and displayed in a graph, the data will need to be stored in case users wish to look back at previous data. I would certainly need to store it for a couple of months, ideally storing it indefinitely so that users can see all the data they have ever entered if they wish

Comment: 10 users entering 100 numbers once a day makes no difference.  100000 users entering 10000 numbers every 10 minutes I'd look at something other then either one DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have worked a lot more with PostgreSQL than with MySQL

From a performance/scalability point of view both are probably pretty much the same. There are workloads where Postgres is better and there are workloads where MySQL is better. Unless you test it in your environment it's hard to tell which one would work better for you.

Postgres seems (seemed?) to be faster in a workload with a lot of concurrent writes, whereas MySQL seems to be better with heavy read-only workload. But those benchmarks are about 3-4 years old now, so they are probably no longer true - especially since InnoDB in MySQL 5.5 improved a lot in that area.

However PostgreSQL's SQL features are far more advanced than MySQL's and MySQL has a tendency to silently ignore things you tell it to do - especially in a default installation (and if you rely on a foreign key to be created that might be a very unpleasant surprise). MySQL still has an advantage in terms of clustering as far as I can tell.

They are both equal when it comes to High Availability solutions.

I strongly disagree with the opinion that one should avoid any DBMS specific features - utilizing all features of a DBMS will make your application more scalable and will increase performance.

Traditionally MySQL wasn't known for stability and quality of their [releases](http://monty-says.blogspot.com/2008/11/oops-we-did-it-again-mysql-51-released.html), but that seems to have improved since Oracle has taken over.

I still don't like MySQL's release policy where they introduce major changes and features in minor releases. The PostgreSQL dev team has a much more strict policy about what goes into a minor release. Upgrading a minor release (i.e. bugfix releases) is much less "dangerous" in PostgreSQL than it is in MySQL.

Someone once said the big difference between the PG development and MySQL is: the Postgres team first makes sure your data is safe, then it makes sure everything is working correctly, then it makes it fast. Whereas the MySQL team first makes it fast, then correct and finally stable. But that too might have changed since the Oracle takeover.

Personally I'd always prefer PostgreSQL over MySQL because of the much better SQL feature set and the overall quality of the product.

Comment: thanks very much for this comprehensive response, this is exactly the kind of answer that I had hoped for that allows me to get a greater understanding of the relative merits and demerits of both DBs. much appreciated

Comment: +1 "PostgreSQL's SQL features are far more advanced than MySQL's"

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is the more popular solution and is used by very large companies for very large databases, so MySQL is far from unscalable.

If you want the ability to move between both databases at a later date in case you decide to switch, I would recommend using an ORM (Look at http://www.doctrine-project.org/); this way you'll only have to write the queries once and if you change to a different database down the road, you only need to change a config variable. Doctrine will also have you build your database structure in a YAML file which it can convert for you as well.
It's also capable of migrating between database types.

You'll also want to take into account the different MySQL Engines which perform differently as well. I was just looking at a comparison between PostgreSQL and MySQL which in their conclusion, they didn't like the fact that MySQL wasn't built with transactions, however, InnoDB does provide transactional support for MySQL as well as speed and memory improvements in some cases.

So the bottom line is this: If you can make your application in such a way that you can use either database (as mentioned above) run your own benchmarks against your application and your databases and see what kind of a difference it makes to you.

There's certainly other things to think about if you have the budget for it and that's getting DBA's specific to the database you're using and get them to optimize it.

Comment: thanks Francis I will be sure to check out the link you posted

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL is SQL, be sure that you use strict SQL, then you don't rewrite anything. The different between the both dbs is the level of SQL support. PosgreSQL has better support, but the support by MySQL depends on the used storage engine.

Yes, you can better scale your application with PostgeSQL, but how mach load have you on your server? 1GB per day, less more?

Comment: I agree. In time, I assume @timUK will not delete records, it will become sensitive in volume, where PostgreSQL is said that works better as in transactions and new inserts or updates.

Comment: I currently have no load on my server, I only began learning about web development 3 weeks ago, I come from a finance background and so I am very new to this but I am ambitious and determined to learn. I didn't realise that the two databases used the same language, I looked at some of the instructions on the PostgreSQL website and it appeared to be a language that I had not seen in my limited experience of mySQL. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @tfb785 Not sure why you think MySQL isn't scalable. Care to expand on that?

Comment: I don't think it isn't scalable, I am a beginner in web development and I am simply quoting what I have read elsewhere, I just wanted to get people's thoughts on it before I went down one road or another

Comment: I know both DB, and my experiences say, that it easier to scale postgres then mysql, for example with postgresql you can use partioned tables. This technique can boost high load systems.

Comment: @tfb785: I just love PostgreSQL and kind of hate MySQL, but partitioning just sucks in PostgreSQL and is pretty easy to use in MySQL... All other SQL works much better in PostgreSQL, but partitioning is still a PITA.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I understand what you mean, portioning tables is still hand work at PostgeSQL. But in my context (high load, writing) its works relay fine.

Comment: @tfb785 You use partitioning of tables as one of the benefits of PostgreSQL over MySQL, but this is a feature also found in MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @Atonewell Yes its fine the MySQl 5.1 has also partition Tables. The handling in MySQL in Postgres is different. But if you know what you doing and why you do it, you can do with every system.